# How to change database column name via Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a following code:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Category : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

This syntax

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().Property(x => x.Children).HasColumnName("CategoryID");
```

gives me Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0453  The type 'ICollection' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'StructuralTypeConfiguration.Property(Expression>)'

Q: How I can change database column name via Fluent API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collection *itself* can't be mapped to one column. You should map this as a one-to-many association:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Children)
            .WithOptional()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("CategoryID"));
```